# How to code firefox extension which run javascript code in the page's context like firebug does

Tags: javascript, firebug, firefox-addon

I know that for safety reasons that this is not easy to achieve, however there would be a way to do so as firebug does...

Please help, would like to invoke some script in the page's context to achieve some effect...

Basically, I would like to achieve two functionality:
1. add jQuery to any web page automatically if not already exist.
2. when open certain address, call a method of that page to auto notify the server. (an ajax functionality of the page)

I have tried to inject  on the body, no luck.
tried to get the window object, which however do not have access to call the function.

Will try to change the location to something like: javascript:alert('test inject');

Many thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after reading some official documentation and the GreaseMonkey's source, I get the following method which basically works for me.

Hope it will save sb's hour:

```
var appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent");   // browser  
    if (appcontent) {
         appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (evnt) {
            var doc = evnt.originalTarget; 
            var win = doc.defaultView;
            var unsafeWin = win.wrappedJSObject;

            // vote.up is the function on the page's context
            // which is take from this site as example
            unsafeWin.vote.up(...);
         }, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note that using unsafeWin in this way is incredibly dangerous. For example, it is legal for a malicious page to do

var vote = {
  get up: function() {
    [[get-window-object]].Components.classes ["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance (Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
    // web page may now has access to your local filesystem.
  }
}

this will not work directly since the global scope is different, but it is easy to by accident allow a script to get a handle to window (e.g. return values or arguments object).

Answer (score 1):

[Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/) does that.  If you are developing your own extension with similar functionality, you can use [Components.utils.evalInSandbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Components.utils.evalInSandbox).

Comment: Yes, thank you.
I just wondering how to make an extension without dependent on GreaseMonkey...